# Mostrar divs dependiendo de dos selects

Tags: formularios, select, div, submit, show

Quisiera saber como puedo mostrar divs que dependen de dos select y de un botón submit. El problema que tengo es que el segundo select varia dependiendo de lo que se escoja en el primero, entonces no se como puedo mostrar diferentes divs según las variables que tengan los select.

Agradezco la ayuda y este es el código:

```js
//Efecto del botón---------------------------------------------------------------

var e = document.getElementById('open-button');
e.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.className == 'on') this.classList.remove('on');
  else this.classList.add('on');
});

//Código para abrir el menu----------------------------------------------------------

$('nav').hide();
$("#open-button").click(function() {
  $("nav").slideToggle('slow');
});

//Campos para seleccionar paises y sus destinos--------------------------------------

//<![CDATA[ 
// array of possible countries in the same order as they appear in the country selection list 
var countryLists = new Array(6)
countryLists["empty"] = ["Select a Country"];
countryLists["Canada"] = ["Canada", "United States", "Mexico"];
countryLists["Colombia"] = ["Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Ecuador"];
countryLists["Estados Unidos"] = ["Russia", "China", "Japan"];
countryLists["China"] = ["Britain", "France", "Spain", "Germany"];
countryLists["Mexico"] = ["Argentina", "Peru", "Portugal", "Jamaica"];
/* CountryChange() is called from the onchange event of a select element. 
 * param selectObj - the select object which fired the on change event. 
 */
function countryChange(selectObj) {
  // get the index of the selected option 
  var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex;
  // get the value of the selected option 
  var which = selectObj.options[idx].value;
  // use the selected option value to retrieve the list of items from the countryLists array 
  cList = countryLists[which];
  // get the country select element via its known id 
  var cSelect = document.getElementById("innercountry");
  // remove the current options from the country select 
  var len = cSelect.options.length;
  while (cSelect.options.length > 0) {
    cSelect.remove(0);
  }
  var newOption;
  // create new options 
  for (var i = 0; i < cList.length; i++) {
    newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = cList[i]; // assumes option string and value are the same 
    newOption.text = cList[i];
    // add the new option 
    try {
      cSelect.add(newOption); // this will fail in DOM browsers but is needed for IE 
    } catch (e) {
      cSelect.appendChild(newOption);
    }
  }
}
//]]>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <p>Selecciona el país del cual quieres conocer las rutas marítimas y sus respectivos paises de destino</p>

  <div class="fields-container">

    <label for="country"><h4>País de origen</h4></label>
    <select id="country" onchange="countryChange(this);">
      <option value="empty">Selecciona el país de origen</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canadá</option>
      <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
      <option value="Estados Unidos">Estados Unidos</option>
      <option value="China">China</option>
      <option value="Mexico">México</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label for="innercountry"><h4 class="titleincountry">País de destino</h4></label>
    <select id="innercountry"><br/>
      <option value="0">Paises de destino</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="send" name="submit" value="Consulta las rutas">

  </div>

</form>



<!-- (These are the divs that I want to show (prueba and pruebauno)) Mapa Principal y minimapas con animación -->
<section>

  <div class="map">

    <div id="open-button"><span></span><span></span></div>
    <img src="image/map.png">
    <div class="prueba"></div>
    <div class="pruebauno"></div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Te propongo crear dicho select y ponerlo en oculto (`style="visibility:hidden"`). Luego crea un script en AJAX para que al seleccionar un país, según cual sea lo ponga visible o lo deje oculto. Se hace así porque una vez cargada la página no puedes modificar dichos campos, pues deberías volver a recargar la página. Con AJAX, en cambio, puedes hacer este tipo de cosas sin recargar dicha página

Comment: no esta claro lo que quieres hacer al seleccionar los paises origen y destino. ¿De que forma los divs que quieres mostrar dependen de estos 2 selects?